# How to play back a sound in Visual Basic twice

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to build an educational app for a child with severe disabilities. It is supposed to teach the child how to add two numbers ranging from 1 - 9. In order to do so, I want to make it play back a sound, consisting of n (the number the child clicked) times the sound "one.wav". I use the following code:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To buttonNumber
            i = i + 1
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("one.wav")
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
Next
```

While it does play the sound, the number of times is highly irregular and does not equal "buttonNumber". What is the problem? (Note that I've tried the same code without the "i = i + 1".)

EDIT:

The following piece of code does NOT work:

```
Private Sub PlayButtonAudio(buttonNumber As Integer)
        Dim bytes As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("one.wav")

        For i As Integer = 1 To buttonNumber
            My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(bytes, AudioPlayMode.Background)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(playDuration)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Quite curiously though, it works perfecty whenever "buttonNumber" is larger than or equal to four.

Comment: [SoundPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer) -> [`SoundPlayer.PlaySync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.playsync). Remove that `Thread.Sleep(1000)`. It would be wise to specify the full path of the media file.

Comment: This did not work either; the sound played twice where it should only play once. Still correct for "buttonNumber" variable >= 4.

Comment: If it *didn't work* it's probably because you used `SoundPlayer.Play()` instead of `SoundPlayer.PlaySync()` or you added other code, as loading the sound file inside the loop etc. Otherwise *it works*, no doubts on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had the first three buttons twice in the handler list. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The 1000 milliseconds you've specified is from the start of the playing wav, so you'll need the time gap to add the length of the sound.  The audio begins to play through the OS and your code continues while it's playing.  If you attempt to play it a second time while the first is still playing you'll run into problems.

There may be other methods of playing audio which don't return to your code until the audio is complete, but this would freeze your UI.

[Edit: Unless you do it in a separate thread.  But for your purposes it's possibly simpler to just increase the delay.]

Answer (score 0):

The `My.Computer.Audio` component is using a shared system resource and the `Play` method is just a wrapper around the API [PlaySound function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)).

I am assuming that you only want the sound to play for a maximum of the sleep duration. If it takes the system longer than specified sleep duration (or a significant portion thereof) to load the WAV file into memory, the first playback may be mishandled.  This effect can be mitigated by loading WAV into a byte array and using the `Play` overload that takes a byte array instead of a file name.

As you are using a shared resource, other sounds may be playing; calling `My.Computer.Audio.Stop()` will cancel anything currently playing.

```
Const playDuration As Integer = 1000 ' milliseconds

' load the WAV file into a byte array
' this will minimize the latency caused by loading the file from disc
Dim bytes As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("one.wav")


For i As Integer = 1 To buttonNumber
  My.Computer.Audio.Stop() ' cancel any currently playing sound
  My.Computer.Audio.Play(bytes, AudioPlayMode.Background)
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(playDuration)
Next
My.Computer.Audio.Stop() ' cancel playing if wav file duration is longer than playDuration
```